# In google chrome, scroll bar won't work till I change zoom on page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

I don't know if this is a browser issue but I am using Google Chrome. Now lets say I append a couple of table rows and suddenly a scroll bar appears for the table (I stated that after 500px, display a scroll bar in my css). Now if I try to use the scroll bar, it wouldn't move, I realize that if I change the zoom for the browser's web page, then use the scroll bar, then it scrolls.

Now everytime I append a row, I need to change the zoom and then change it back for then for me to able able to use the scroll bar.

Is this just a glitch from the browser or is it something I have done wrong?

In firefox it seems like the scroll bar works fine without any problems after appending a row.

The basic css for scroll table is below:

```
#details{
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide a link to test, thx.

Comment: Without the example code, I'm not completely sure how to help :(

Comment: I tried to [reproduce your problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhxNJ/), without any success. I had to put the table in a div to have scrollbars. [Without it](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhxNJ/1/), the table just keep on growing...

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for lateness, just had to do a couple of things, anyway I have a jsfiddle here where you can see the code. Please test this in your google chrome and see if same happens to you. Im guessing it might struggle to scroll in chrome because the table takes up the width of the browser but not sure. http://jsfiddle.net/WZKrP/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change overflow to `scroll`. Good way to test if something could potentially be wrong with your append.

Comment: I included a fiddle in comments above for you to be able to see and text my app. Can you paste the code in your source editor and then run it in chrome and see if you get same problem. Btw if I change to scroll then it doesn't change anything

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce what you're seeing, but not sure why it's not working the way it should be.

Comment: Its ok, it must be chrome that has this problem, firefox and opera don't have this problem at all